# how to get the size of a swift type and of a swift object?

Tags: swift

Apple documentation on MemoryLayout ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout?changes=latest_minor) says this:

[image]

But then,if I try to replicate it I get:

[image]

So what's the way to get the size of a type and of an object in swift?

Comment: Please post *code* together with the expected and actual output.

Comment: `class Point` is a *reference type,* so what you get is the size of a pointer.

Comment: Related: [Get the size (in bytes) of an object on the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40312123/2976878)

Comment: @MartinR: why you are asking why? I want to know because I want to print it

Comment: @onthemoon Did you see the Q&A I linked to? On Apple platforms (such as you appear to be), you can use `class_getInstanceSize` in order to get the size of a class instance, and AFAIK should always give reliable results.